# Extract text between variable delimiters

Tags: r, regex

I have text with large numbers of special characters that I want to extract certain substrings from:

```
y <- c("some stuff <rep> I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% </rep> some stuff <#> <dir> where is Londonderry?</dir>",
       "some stuff <rep> <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% </rep> <#> potentially more stuff <rep> I 1lIved in Lisburn </rep>",
       "<xpa> <[> <unclear> 3 sylls </unclear> </[> </{> </xpa> blah blub <icu> Yeah </icu>")
```

I want to extract whatever comes between 'tag' like substrings, either `<dir> ...</dir>` or `<rep> ...</rep>`  or `<icu> ...</icu>` and so on:

With this regex I'm modestly successful:

```
library(stringr)
lapply(y, function(x) paste0(unlist(str_extract_all(x, "<([a-z]{3})>(?!<\\1>).*</\\1>")), collapse = ", "))
[[1]]
[1] "<rep> I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% </rep>, <dir> where is Londonderry?</dir>"

[[2]]
[1] "<rep> <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% </rep> <#> potentially more stuff <rep> I 1lIved in Lisburn </rep>"

[[3]]
[1] "<xpa> <[> <unclear> 3 sylls </unclear> </[> </{> </xpa>, <icu> Yeah </icu>"
```

Just `[[2]]`isn't as expected: there is still unwanted material (namely `<#> potentially more stuff`) and the two occurrences of `<rep> ...</rep>` substrings are not separated by `,`. My hunch is that my regex fails here because the two tags are the same rather than different.

How can the regex be improved so that this **expected result** is obtained:

**Expected result**:

```
[[1]]
[1] "<rep> I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% </rep>, <dir> where is Londonderry?</dir>"

[[2]]
[1] "<rep> <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% </rep>, <rep> I 1lIved in Lisburn </rep>"

[[3]]
[1] "<xpa> <[> <unclear> 3 sylls </unclear> </[> </{> </xpa>, <icu> Yeah </icu>"
```

**EDIT**:

I've found a viable solution in the meantime:

```
lapply(y, function(x) paste0(unlist(str_extract_all(x, "<([a-z]{3})>.*?</\\1>")), collapse = ", "))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
unlist(str_extract_all(y, "\\<([A-Za-z0-9_]+\\>).*?(\\<\\/\\1)"))

# [1] "<rep> I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% </rep>" "<dir> where is Londonderry?</dir>"                         
# [3] "<rep> <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% </rep>"    "<rep> I 1lIved in Lisburn </rep>"                          
# [5] "<xpa> <[> <unclear> 3 sylls </unclear> </[> </{> </xpa>"    "<icu> Yeah </icu>"
```

Basically all we're doing here is putting the (opening) tag's body (+ its tailing angular bracket) in a capture group, and using that capture group to define the closing tag as well. Then we capture everything between those two instances of said capture group(s). So something like: `<(tag>)whatever<\\1` where `\1` is `tag>`.

Edit:

I guess this should do it:

```
lapply(str_extract_all(y, "\\<([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\>.*?\\<\\/\\1\\>"), paste, collapse = ", ")

# [[1]]
# [1] "<rep> I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% </rep>, <dir> where is Londonderry?</dir>"

# [[2]]
# [1] "<rep> <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% </rep>, <rep> I 1lIved in Lisburn </rep>"

# [[3]]
# [1] "<xpa> <[> <unclear> 3 sylls </unclear> </[> </{> </xpa>, <icu> Yeah </icu>"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What is novel about your solution is not the use of backreference, which you explain at length - that's also used in exactly the same way in the OP - but the use of the lazy dot. Also, there's no need for this comprehensive character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, `[a-z]` will do.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann please seem the edit to my answer.

Comment: I've seen it but for me to accept it you'd have to edit your answer more. Also: the edited solution looks very much like my edited solution (which was earlier) ...

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann well there are only so many ways to unlist a list and collapse a bunch of strings. For the record, I did not base this off of the edit in the OP (which I've noticed only now). It's absolutely fine if you don't "accept" the answer, I'm not in it for the points/reputation/whatever. I think I've helped you somehow (with the lazy regex quantifier), and I learned something along the way, so that's more than enough for me.

Comment: Believe it or not, the idea of using the lazy quantifier occurred to me shortly after I'd posted the question. I'll accept your answer anyway so you benefit from your effort and (I'll be happy about the two points off of accepting too).

Answer (score 4):

```
library(gsubfn)
a1 <- strapplyc(y, "<dir>(.*?)</dir>", simplify = c)
a2 <- strapplyc(y, "<rep>(.*?)</rep>", simplify = c)
a3 <- strapplyc(y, "<icu>(.*?)</icu>", simplify = c)

a1
a2
a3

# output:
> a1
[1] " where is Londonderry?"
> a2
[1] " I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% " " <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% "   
[3] " I 1lIved in Lisburn "                          
> a3
[1] " Yeah "
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but that's not quite the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your problem corectly, this is a possible solution (I use the rebus package a lot for regex related problems - the result is a conventional regex):

```
library(dplyr)
library(rebus)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

y <- c("some stuff <rep> I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% </rep> some stuff <#> <dir> where is Londonderry?</dir>",
       "some stuff <rep> <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% </rep> <#> potentially more stuff <rep> I 1lIved in Lisburn </rep>",
       "<xpa> <[> <unclear> 3 sylls </unclear> </[> </{> </xpa> blah blub <icu> Yeah </icu>")

pattern <- "<" %R% ANY_CHAR %R% ANY_CHAR %R% ANY_CHAR %R% ">" %R% ".*?" %R% "<" %R% "/" %R% ANY_CHAR %R% ANY_CHAR %R% ANY_CHAR %R% ">" 

stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(y ,pattern, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
  purrr::map(~paste0(.x, collapse = ", "))

[[1]]
[1] "<rep> I 1knOw 2LondondErry is bigger than 2LIsburn% </rep>, <dir> where is Londonderry?</dir>"

[[2]]
[1] "<rep> <[> But it 's 1nOt an overflow of Belfast% </rep>, <rep> I 1lIved in Lisburn </rep>"

[[3]]
[1] "<xpa> <[> <unclear> 3 sylls </unclear> </[> </{> </xpa>, <icu> Yeah </icu>"
```